# How to customize Feature image for a SharePoint 2010 Sandbox solution?

Tags: feature, sharepoint-foundation, sandbox-solution, image

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Own Feature-Icon in Sandbox Solutions](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/13035/own-feature-icon-in-sandbox-solutions)

Ok, as usual, after searching for a solution on the *rest* of the net, here I am on StackExchange :)

How can I stuff a PNG image in my sandboxed solution, so that the feature can refer to it and use it as the feature image? And which path should I use to refer to it?

I am talking about the 31x22 image whose relative path goes into `ImageUrl` attribute of the `Feature` XML node in feature manifest file.

This is in order to get something different than this  [image: default feature icon]

I've already looked on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms436075.aspx), [SPRoot](http://sharepointroot.com/2009/10/13/site-feature-include-custom-icon-gif/), and [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/704893/sharepoint-solution-packaging-how-do-i-get-a-custom-icon-for-my-features).

**EDIT:** Uhm, it looks like I haven't looked enough. The answer is right here: [How to customize Feature image for a sandbox solution?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/13035/own-feature-icon-in-sandbox-solutions).
And it's no.

Could  somebody please close this answer as duplicate?